# Generate iframe using php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, iframe, codeigniter-2

I have a question...I generate an iframe for a video in my site but when I tried to open this iFrame is open all the page not only the video..
This is my iframe:

```
<iframe width="650" height="370" src="mysite.com/video/8/620" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

My function for generate iframe:

```
function iframe() {

    if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {
        $videoid = (int) $this->uri->segment(3);
    } else {
        $videoid = 0;
    }

    $this->tpl->assign("theid", $videoid);
    $this->tpl->assign("SITE_URL", config_item('site_url'));

    $this->tpl->display('video/iframe.tpl');
}
```

Help me please

Answer (score 1):

You need to include Not the Url to the Page, where The Video is in it. You should include the video drectly.

```
<iframe width="650" height="370" src="mysite.com/video/8/620/videofile.mp4" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Maybe you want to make use of Video Tag:

```
<video>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```